# FAILED: chrome org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown error has occurred in **Selenoid**

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid, selenoid

Trying to run selenoid in my aws ec2 server

java code:-

```
 @Test
      public void chrome() throws MalformedURLException{
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capabilities.setVersion("80.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("enableVNC", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("enableVideo", false);
        RemoteWebDriver   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new 
       URL("http://x2.66.24x.xxx:4444/wd/hub"),capabilities);

         driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com");

          WebElement hello = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
            hello.sendKeys("hello");

            hello.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            driver.close();
    }
```

while running above code I can see new a session is created for chrome browser all operation will get 
perform but at the end, it will through exception & **Same error i'm getting for firefox as well** :

**Apr 01, 2020 10:59:15 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
Apr 01, 2020 10:59:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Apr 01, 2020 11:01:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
FAILED: chrome
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown error has occurred
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-B5FT9H4U', ip: 'xx.1xx.x9.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 80.0.3987.132, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.7xE3Rs}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:40995}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 2936e2a690849c764a8e00dd5f7001da**

Comment: Show us your `browsers.json` file contents example.

Comment: As per document, I didn't create any JSON file I'm just working with basic features. correct me we create json file only when we need to add some addition config to the selenoid.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and managed to solve it (at least for now) by increasing the session timeout:

```
capabilities.setCapability("sessionTimeout", "5m");
```